# Mobile Ads Refresh Rate & Optimization

Tags: mobile, ads, mopub

I'm looking to add mobile ads using Mopub.

In thinking where and on which activities to place ads, I'm thinking more screen views = more ad refreshes = more CPM impressions

However Mopub's guide emphasizes click throughs and asks not to refresh the ad often. I think their ad refreshes after a timeout by itself anyways.
http://www.mopub.com/2011/10/12/how-to-optimize-your-mobile-ads-part-2-of-3/

I'm a little confused as that approach would mean less ad impressions. What am I missing?

Obviously I'm trying to optimize ad placement for profitability.

Should I refresh often myself for each activity & fragment load? Or is it best to reload less frequently ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trade off since Higher CTR (Click Through Rate) means higher eCPM (estimated cost per mille (impression)) ads. However, with a faster refresh, you get more ad impressions but the CTR drops ad there is less screen time for an individual ad.

For banners, I'd say about a 20-30s refresh rate is optimal. I know that for MoPub, you can set values lower than 10, but the minimum is around 10 seconds for refresh rate.

You can run a a/b test programmatically on MoPub for two subsets of users, one with an ad unit with 20s and one with an ad unit with 30s and see which one performs better.

For MoPub, you can automatically set refresh rate by editing the ad unit in the UI.